# Poco exception = /home/msy/ros_ws/devel/lib//libgrid_layer.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2tf11Transformer18DEFAULT_CACHE_TIMEE

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a custom costmap plugin.

It can work on local costmap.The configuration is as follows:

> plugins:
> - {name: grid_layer, type: "simple_layer_namespace::GridLayer"}
> - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

But if I configure it to the global costmap,it will report an error.

> [ INFO] [1688106907.862182415, 1687920714.481622674]: global_costmap: Using plugin "grid_layer"
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
> what():  Failed to load library /home/msy/ros_ws/devel/lib//libgrid_layer.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/msy/ros_ws/devel/lib//libgrid_layer.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2tf11Transformer18DEFAULT_CACHE_TIMEE)

The configuration is as follows:

> plugins:
> # - {name: static_layer,    type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
> # - {name: obstacle_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
> - {name: grid_layer, type: "simple_layer_namespace::GridLayer"}
> - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

What went wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417037/poco-exception-=-/home/msy/ros_ws/devel/lib//libgrid_layer.so:-undefined-symbol:-_zn2tf11transformer18default_cache_timee/) by [peter_feng](https://answers.ros.org/users/140466/peter_feng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Transformer" is part of the tf ros package, so in your CMakeLists.txt you need to specify that your plugin has a dependency on this package. There are other tf-related ros packages you may also need (tf2, tf2_ros, tf_conversions), but I'm pretty sure that particular error is from tf.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter_feng](https://answers.ros.org/users/140466/peter_feng/) on 2023-07-03**:
I added all of them(tf, tf2_ros, tf_conversions) to the configuration file.

It worked! Thank you.